# Subscript out of bounds when using conditional by in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to list unique IDs within groups, where the grouping variable can be selected by the user. The following works:

```
if(useGroupVar1){

  dt[,unique(id),.(group1a,group1b,group1c)]

} else {

  dt[,unique(id),group2]

}
```

The expressions I'm using in my code to filter rows are actually fairly long so I want to avoid duplicating code. I came up with this "solution", which doesn't actually work:

```
dt[,unique(id),if(useGroupVar1){.(group1a,group1b,group1c)}else{group2}]
```

If the condition leads to using `group2` alone, it works (though the column is called `if`), but trying to get it to use `.(group1a,group1b,group1c)` results in

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "."

Now, I read `.()` is an alias to `list()`, so using the latter gets me this

> Error in bysubl[[jj + 1L]] : subscript out of bounds

Is there a way to implement a conditional `by` without duplicating entire expressions?

Comment: Did you try it with a normal character vector (quoted)?

Comment: I would do exactly this: `by = if (useGroupVar1) paste0('group1', c('a','b','c')) else 'group2')`

Comment: Did that and got this very descriptive error! `Error in \`[.data.table\`(tabla, if (identical(codificacion[[1]][i]$codCIE,  : 
  'by' appears to evaluate to column names but isn't c() or key(). Use by=list(...) if you can. Otherwise, by=eval(if (!porEESS) {    c("cod_dpto", "cod_prov", "cod_dist")} else {    cod_2000}) should work. This is for efficiency so data.table can detect which columns are needed.`

Comment: Or just add a line above your `[` call: `group_var = if (...) else `. Then `dt[ , , by = group_var]`.

Comment: I see. Then yes, my second comment should work.

Comment: And indeed, wrapping `eval()` around the whole thing fixed the issue. I'm left wondering about the inner workings of `data.table` and the arcane details of why very similar expressions don't work as expected.

Comment: @MichaelChirico More specifically: with `by=` as the argument to `unique` like `unique(dt, by = your_expression_plus_id)`. No need for `DT[...]` eh. Downside is it leaves some extra columns, I guess. Alternately, `unique(DT[, expression_for_columns, with=FALSE])`.

Comment: Re the arcane details, I guess `by=` does only one check for `.()` wrapping the whole expression. It doesn't like `c(.(a), .(b))` either: `DT = data.table(a = 1:2, b= 3:4, d = 5:6); DT[, max(d), by=c(.(a), .(b))]`. I don't really know, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just personal preference, but I don't like pasting strings in a `by=` statement of a data.table (not very readable to me).

Instead, I would use a user-selected variable (`var`) and create a list of grouping variables. Then, you can easily select the variables like so:

```
groupVars <- list(
  GroupVar1 = c("group1a","group1b","group1c"),
  GroupVar2 = c("groupXYZ", "groupABC"),
  GroupVarX = "group2"
)

# user selects that - for example - var = "GroupVar2"

dt[, unique(id), by = groupVars[[var]]]
```

**As a side note:**

You can easily extend this kind of variable selection for situations where a user is allowed to select multiple sets of grouping variables. In such cases, you could it as follows:

Assume, that the user-selected variable is now:

```
var <- c("GroupVar1", "GroupVarX") # two groups selected
```

Then, the `by=` statement becomes:

```
dt[, unique(id), by = unlist(groupVars[var], use.names=FALSE)]
```

Comment: I would even just use `switch` _a la_ `groupVars = switch(var, GroupVar1 = ...)`

Comment: Last line can be `unique(dt[, c(groupVars[[var]], "id")])`, I guess.

Comment: @Frank, true, but that's a more specific case, whereas my answer was supposed to be general for data.table by= statements

Comment: Re the side note, seems likely the candidate groupVars would have some overlap, so maybe `Reduce(union, groupVars[var])` or similar.